# Why I cannot initialize dummy interface at bashrc?

Tags: centos, networking, startup, autostart, virtual-interface

I did try to initialize a dummy interface in shell manually without no problem. In order to bring up this interface at every boot up process, then i tried to add it to `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/profile` as below:

```
ip link set name eth0 dev dummy0
ip link set eth0 address d0:17:c2:a9:a5:5e
ifconfig eth0 hw ether d0:17:c2:a9:a5:5e
```

‌I also added below config to `/etc/modules-load.d/dummy.conf` but it did not worked as well.

```
/sbin/ip link set name eth0 dev dummy0
```

Comment: you can't if your not root

Comment: @Kiwy does `/etc/bashrc` run in root user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most of the distros the answer for executing commands at the boot is /etc/rc.local (today this includes redhat and new versions of debian, but you need to create the rc.local file first). So create a script as /etc/rc.local (if it does not exists - if it is already there, just include the lines before exit 0).

The file contents must have an exit 0 on the end.

```
#!/bin/bash

ip link set name eth0 dev dummy0
ip link set eth0 address d0:17:c2:a9:a5:5e
ifconfig eth0 hw ether d0:17:c2:a9:a5:5e 

exit 0
```

and after that remember to make it executable with:

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

If that works for you please mark this as the correct answer.

In the most of cases you don't want to create a service or to use another solution that can change the peace with your boot system, as rc.local is a "user place" for doing things like that.

Good Lucky!

Comment: `chmod +x etc/rc.d/rc.local` is also required.

Answer (score 0):

Surely not /etc/bashrc or /etc/profile
This is for bash session or login profile. Used when you start bash or log in

Depends on your linux distro. But in red hat you would create file   in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts 
Look documentation for detail

Comment: Is it possible to bring up a *dummy* interface in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scrips` during boot up? I could not find a good solution yet